# Multiple thead getting created in DOM

Tags: html

Is there anything wrong with the HTML below?

1. It creates two thead's in the DOM.
2. The source (Ctrl+U) looks okay - exactly how I've written.

I am using Firefox.

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="interactions" class="tablesorter" style="width:600px; height=1024px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="800">Charts</th>
            <th width="20">Chi Square p-value</th>
        </tr>
    <thead/>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's screenshot of DOM for the HTML.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`<thead/>`  is a self-closing tag, not a closing tag.
Since `<thead>`s cannot be nested, the parser implicitly closes the previous tag first.

Move the `/`.